# Return to sender view controller from deep linked view controller ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, deep-linking

I am using deep linking in iOS app. When a user on any screen in the App clicks on a app specific schema link , he is directed to a `viewcontroller` handled in the `AppDelegate`'s 
`application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation`

But the problem is that I want to create a back button in this new opened view controller pressing which I wish to return to the view controller on which the user clicked the link, basically popping the view.

I tried using `popViewControllerAnimated`, but it didnt work.

```
NotificationViewController *detailViewController = [[NotificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NotificationViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

UINavigationController *navView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];
navView.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.window.rootViewController = navView;
```

Comment: Can you show some code

Comment: It really depends on how you present the new viewcontroller. Are you presenting it modally? Pushing it onto a navigation stack? Replacing the root viewcontroller entirely?

Comment: @James how do i get access to the navigationController in appdelegate to push it onto the stack.??